# Event KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp How to get the name of the pressed button?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tell me, how can I get the name of the button you clicked on?

Example:

```
public void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs key)
{
    MessageBox.Show(key.GetName()); //For example: Enter or some other button
}
```

Comment: ((Control)sender).Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button has a `Name` property. The button (or any other element that fired the event) is `sender`. But maybe what's confusing if you are not used to it, is that `sender` is loosely typed as `object`, and `object` doesn't have `Name`, so you won't find it directly in your autocomplete, and it would not compile if you wrote `sender.Name`.

You can cast the `sender` as the proper class. For instance `Button`, etc... A good reusable solution is just to use `Control` as Hans Passant commented. Something like :

```
if (sender is Control control)
{
    MessageBox.Show(control.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "button" you mean the keyboard key (and I'm not sure what that has to do with clicking, maybe on screen keyboard?) ...

The `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events pass `KeyEventArgs`.

There's a lot of properties to investigate, but you can simply do:

```
MessageBox.Show(key.KeyCode.ToString()); //For example: Enter [Return] or some other button [key]
```

The `KeyPress` event passes `KeyPressEventArgs`, which is not as verbose.

You might try:

```
MessageBox.Show(key.KeyChar.ToString());
```

...as the name suggests, it's just the character.